# How to custom id input on field in form ui component Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, custom

How to custom id input on field in form ui component Magento 2?
Here's my code:

```
<input class="admin__control-text" type="text" data-bind="
    event: {change: userChanges},
    value: value,
    hasFocus: focused,
    valueUpdate: valueUpdate,
    attr: {
        name: inputName,
        placeholder: placeholder,
        'aria-describedby': noticeId,
        id: uid,
        disabled: disabled,
        maxlength: 255
}" name="general[sku]" aria-describedby="notice-MBFNF2H" id="MBFNF2H" maxlength="255">
```

I want custom id field input.

```
$fields = [
    [
        'label' => __('Attribute: '.$nameAttribute),
        'formElement' => 'input',
        'source'=>'general',
        'sortOrder' => 0,
        'validation'=> ['required-entry'=> true]
    ]
];
```